# Default values for DependencyProperties of Types System.Drawing.Font and .Bitmap

Tags: c#, dependency-properties

Here is the code I have :

```
public class CustomWidget
{
    public System.Drawing.Color Value
    {
        get { return (System.Drawing.Color)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(System.Drawing.Color), typeof(Color), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));

    public System.Drawing.Font Valuee
    {
        get { return (System.Drawing.Font)GetValue(ValueeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueeProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Valuee", typeof(System.Drawing.Font), typeof(Font), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

For the Font, I can set a default Font, there is not other way I think, but what about the Bitmap ? Do I absolutelyu have to get a Bitmap in my project that will be referenced for the default value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can simply use `null`.

Comment: hum, always thought I couldnt use "null" as default values for dependency properties... I used this constructor anyway : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7we6s1x3.aspx

Comment: What makes you think you can't use `null`? That's simply not correct. See the samples on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx) page. They all pass `null` as the first parameter to the constructor of `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`...